# Pass multiple variable to other page using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a site and i have to reset the password script on a page. For that i am using ajax for passing the old and new password and want to get the result on the same page

my code for reset page is:-

```
<label>Enter current Password:</label><input id="cur_password" type="password" /><br/>
<label>Enter New Password:</label><input id="new_password" type="password" /><br/>
<label>Confirm New Password:</label><input id="confirm_password" type="password" /><br/>            
<a id="Reset_pass" class="submitButtons" value="Submit">Submit</a>
```

and my java script page for handling this request is:-

```
$('#Reset_pass').click(function(){
var cur_password = $('#cur_password').val();
var new_password = $('#new_password').val();
var confirm_password = $('#confirm_password').val();
$('#current_password').parent().append("<img src=\"includes/ajaxLoader.gif\"");
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxServer.php?request=Reset_password',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'cur_password': cur_password,'new_password': new_password,'confirm_password': confirm_password},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(result){
        $('#current_password').parent().children('img').remove();
        $('#current_password').parent().children('span.updateResults').remove();
        $('#current_password').parent().append(result);
    }
}); 
 });
```

and java script passing the value to a page name ajaxServer as:-

```
  if($request == "Reset_password")
  {
$db_name = "user_mgmt";
include "connections/Con.php";//for database connection
$temp=$_SESSION['username'];
$result = mysql_query("select Password from register where Unique_id=$temp");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$status=strcmp('$_POST[cur_password]','$row[0]');
$confirm_pass=strcmp('$_POST[new_password]','$_POST[confirm_password]');
if(($status==0)&&($confirm_pass==0))
{   
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE register SET Password='$_POST[new_password]' where Unique_id='$temp'");
}
?>
<span class="updateResults">
<?php
if($query){
    echo "Your Password is reset";
}
else{
    echo "Unable ";
}
?>
</span>
}
```

but there is erroe in java script code..tht why it is not able to send info to the ajaxServer page...please help me to find the error...thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell me the name of the site, just so I remember never to trust it with my password.

Comment: You have a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Never** store passwords in plain text.

Comment: @SLaks: yes, but that's OOT I guess

Comment: @LeleDumbo security malpractice and SQL injection is never OOT.

Answer (score 0):

Assign error property as well instead of just success, that way you could catch the error.